Eclipse EGit Pull and Push in one-click
Is there a way in Eclipse using EGit to first git pull then push in one click? Ideally, I would like to assign this to shortcuts.
Right now, I need to enter two shortcuts (one for pull and one for pull). One repo sees a lot of action, so pulling is actually most always needed.
